# which algorithm can be used to detect temporal pattern?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, weka, temporal, mining

I'm trying to detect temporal relations or temporal patterns in my data .
I've used Apriori associater in Weka but seems to ignore the time and find only 
sequences .

can you please suggest a toolkit or package for temporal pattern mining ?

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.8 Weka supports time series analysis using the [timeseriesForecasting](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.packages/timeseriesForecasting/) package.

You can read about it [here](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/Time+Series+Analysis+and+Forecasting+with+Weka), or learn about it in the [Advanced Data Mining with Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/mooc/advanceddataminingwithweka/) MOOC (all videos are also available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/WekaMOOC/videos)).

Comment: Thank you @Lior. but I think I didn't ask properly . Actually, I need to discover the temporal relations in my data using algorithm that is able to detect Allen's temporal relations ( before - after - meet ,,, ) . Or algorithms can show the patterns as rules ex: X->y-> z and so on . I think the Time forcasting package in Weka shows the relations between events not as sequence of events . please let me know if I'm wrong. thanks again.

Comment: I think it would be better if you'll describe your dataset and show some examples of relationships that you expect to find.